# Hiding domain based control on specifications

Tags: javascript, maximo, maximo-anywhere

In Maximo Anywhere, When you have a domain on specification attribute, SpecificationMixin.js creates a a dynamic control using _buildDomainBasedControl method.

You can see the lookup when you click on specification tab and then specification attribute in WorkExecution app.

How can I hide the list of lookup data that comes up.

I tried something like this in js file.

eventContext.listWidget.maxdomains

This returns the correct name of domain that is attached to the specification attribute. But I am unable to hide the domain.

Any ideas/suggestion will be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are inside a 'render' eventHandler in the ; If you want to hide the specification list item itself:

```
var specListItems = eventContext.listWidget.domNode.children;
for(var i =0 ; i< specListItems.length; i++){
    if(specListItems[i].textContent.indexOf("Shaft") > -1){
        specListItems[i].style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

Change the "Shaft" to the attribute name you want to hide.

From your question I am not sure if you want to hide the lookup button and not the list item itself. In that case, you will have to traverse the children inside the for loop and set the lookup button style to none. Also you might want to set the text element to editable to allow the user to input text, instead of selecting from lookup.